# useEffect dependancy array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I'm using customHook to fetch data from an API.

```
const useFetch = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   return async (callback, ...props) => {
      try {
         return await callback(...props);
      } catch (error) {
         const { msg } = error.response?.data || "Something went wrong";
         dispatch(showModal(msg));
         setTimeout(() => dispatch(hideModal()), 3000);
      }
   };
};
```

and using it inside useEffect

```
const customFetch = useFetch();
useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
         const data = await customFetch(fetchUsers, token);
         if (data) setUsers(data.user);
      })();
   }, [token]);
```

But eslint is complaining about the missing customFetch dependency. If I add it it will end up in an infinite loop. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So you just need `useCallback` here to make callback you return stable:

```
const useFetch = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const fetcher = useCallback(async (callback, ...props) => {
      try {
         return await callback(...props);
      } catch (error) {
         const { msg } = error.response?.data || "Something went wrong";
         dispatch(showModal(msg));
         setTimeout(() => dispatch(hideModal()), 3000);
      }
   }, [dispatch]);
   return fetcher;
};
```

`useMemo` and `useCallback` are specifically useful in cases like that, when you need something to be referentially the same, while creating/returning literally would provide new instance on each run(function, array, object)